# Interacting with pytest main response

Tags: pytest

I'm building a testing infrastructure for our company, where the main runner is pytest.

The architecture is to build a docker, expose endpoints via flask (restul-APIs) and have the user invoking tests with using these restful endpoints.
one of the things I have issue with related to pytest.main.

I really can't parse the response that is thrown out, since it only provide exit code.

any other solution for doing it?

(P.S. - I think that I need to build a callback plugin that will just inject the response to some db. the json plugin response plugin looks fine, but I think it needs the traceback to become a bit slim than it is now)

Answer (score 0):

Can you send pytest test run arguments via the rest api endpoint? If you can, use `--junit-xml=path` argument  and return that xml through an endpoint. You can parse that xml for detailed test results. You can also get json output with pytest using `pytest-json` python package (https://pypi.org/project/pytest-json/) and parse the json.

Comment: Great idea.
my only concern is that the pytest-json response will be too bing in order to fetch and parse (the results are embedded)..

Comment: You can prune the test result size by using verbosity control switch like `-v`. Or you can pull the test data only in case of test failure. Return the test result of individual tests.

I would suggest configuring test results to be written in a central db and you can pull test data from there.